# rest POST object using spring for android

Tags: java, android, spring, rest

I'm trying to POST to a rest service using spring for android(I'm new at this)

The restful service has this structure

```
@POST
@Path("/ider")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public SearchOutRO hashTrackInJSON(SearchInRO in);
```

with(shortened object code):

```
public class SearchInRO implements Serializable {
    private Double latitud;
    private Double longitud;
}

public class SearchOutRO implements Serializable {
    private Integer searchId;
}
```

so I'm trying this(from android)

```
String url = BASE_URL + "ider";
HttpHeaders requestHeaders = new HttpHeaders();

requestHeaders.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);

MultiValueMap<String, String> body = new LinkedMultiValueMap<String, String>();
body.add("searchInRO[latitud]", String.valueOf(user.getLatitud()));
body.add("searchInRO[longitud]", String.valueOf(user.getLongitud()));

HttpEntity<?> requestEntity = new HttpEntity<Object>(body, requestHeaders);
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();

List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> messageConverters = new ArrayList<HttpMessageConverter<?>>();
messageConverters.add(new FormHttpMessageConverter());
messageConverters.add(new StringHttpMessageConverter());
restTemplate.setMessageConverters(messageConverters);
try {
    ResponseEntity<SearchOutRO> response = restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.POST, requestEntity, SearchOutRO.class);

    HttpStatus status = response.getStatusCode();
    if (status == HttpStatus.CREATED) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    return false;
}
```

and getting this exception:

```
org.springframework.web.client.RestClientException: Could not write request: no suitable HttpMessageConverter found for request type [org.springframework.util.LinkedMultiValueMap] and content type [application/json]
```

Could you help me pointing out what am I doing wrong?(and how make it right).
I think it may the the "body" MultiValueMap.

Thanks in advance

**EDIT:**  I tried what @Krisl suggested. I succeed to connect to the server side, but it seems the object is not correctly marshalled.

```
WARNING: javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException
 - with linked exception:
[javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException: unexpected element (uri:"", local:"latitud"). Expected elements are <{}searchInRO>]
```

I would appreciate any ideas.

Comment: Do you have access to the server side data objects (`SearchInRO`, `SearchOutRO`) on the client side?

Comment: yes, both locally implemented

Comment: You should use them then, on the client side. Instead of a multi-value map, create a `SearchInRO` object, populate it, and store it into your HttpEntity. I also do not think you need the `FormHttpMessageConverter`.

Comment: Do you have jersey-json jar in your classpath ?

Comment: yes, I don't know exactly what's wrong

Comment: See, answer is updated. make sure you have POJOMappingFeature added in web.xml as init-param

Comment: this is a weird chat...yuo meant add jersey-json to client side?

Comment: yes in client side. If you think this is a weird chat, I am helpless, bye, sorry for wasting your time

Comment: you take it the very wrong way. still can't add a "java core" lib to an android project

Answer (score 4):

it seems to be your assumption is right, MultiValueMap is causing the trouble.

Try this

Instead of using MultiValueMap set the lat and lng in SearchInRO object and add it.

Change

```
HttpEntity<?> requestEntity = new HttpEntity<Object>(body, requestHeaders);
```

to

```
SearchInRO searchInRO = new SearchInRO();
```

set the lat and lng

```
HttpEntity<?> requestEntity = new HttpEntity<Object>(searchInRO , requestHeaders);
```

Also add MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter

```
 messageConverters.add(new MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter());
```

**UPDATE :**
I just checked one of my old project which uses REST and noticed that I used jersey-json jar also (my case maven dependency).
Try this add jersey-json jar to your classpath and update the web.xml like given below

```
<init-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.jersey.api.json.POJOMappingFeature</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
```

Comment: I tried this, and now I get a server error 
'Caused by: javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException: unexpected element'. It seems it fail to marshal to json type.

Comment: Do you have the jackson jars in your classpath

Comment: Take a look at this http://jersey.java.net/nonav/documentation/latest/json.html#json.jaxb.approach.section . Looks like you have XMl annotations in the SearchInRO class

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing `HttpMessageConverter` bean. If you are producing and consuming JSON data, there should be some way to convert java POJO to JSON and vice-versa.
Try adding following bean in your context xml file.

```
<beans:bean id="jacksonMessageChanger"
    class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter">
    <beans:property name="supportedMediaTypes" value="application/json" />
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter">
    <beans:property name="messageConverters">
        <util:list id="beanList">
            <beans:ref bean="jacksonMessageChanger" />
        </util:list>
    </beans:property>
</beans:bean>
```

Also you would need to add maven dependencies for jackson mappers.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-core-asl</artifactId>
    <version>1.8.5</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
    <version>1.8.5</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

diff approach using jackson with a writer to go to string before you set the HttpEntity...

[ref](http://localtone.blogspot.com/2009/07/post-json-using-android-and-httpclient.html)

```
ObjectNode rootOb = new ObjectMapper().createObjectNode();
  { create obj nodes , adding each to rootNode }
  {jackson api to go to string }

    StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
    new ObjectMapper().writeValue(writer, rootOb);
    String poststr=writer.toString();

httpPost.setEntity(new StringEntity(poststr));
```